# Как убрать анимацию?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#nextCarousel").click(function(){
    $(".main-container").animate({
        scrollTop: $('.main-container').scrollTop() + 100
    });
});
```

Здравствуйте, как избавиться от анимации?

Код должен скролить блок на 100 пикселей при каждом нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы наверное как-то так бы сделал:

```js
function scroll() {
  let fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let newScroll = fromTop + 100;
  $(window).scrollTop(newScroll);
}

$("button").on("click", scroll)
```

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid;
}

.block+.block {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
</div>
<button class="btn">click</button>
```

В вашем же случае можно просто для animate поставить duration: 0.

Типа такого:

```js
function scroll() {
  let fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let newScroll = fromTop + 100;
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: newScroll
  }, 0);
}

$("button").on("click", scroll)
```

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid;
}

.block+.block {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
  <div class="block">block</div>
</div>
<button class="btn">click</button>
```

Вот ваш код с duration 0:

```js
$("#nextCarousel").click(function() {
    $(".main-container").animate({
        scrollTop: $('.main-container').scrollTop() + 100
    }, 0);
});
```